# Update many records.should i use cursor?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

i have a problem with Update in Ms Sql Server(TSQL)
suppose that i have a table **Person** with **Description** and **ID** fields and inserted 1000 record to this table with this value

```
  1      Descript1
  2      Descript2
  3      Descript3
  ..       ......
  ..      ......
  1000   Descript1000
```

how can i change this 1000 record same below record

```
1   Description1
2    Description2
3     Description3
......
......
1000      Description1000
```

should i use **cursor**?
i wrote this query but it doesnt work

```
    while @Counter<=1000000
      begin
          update Person set Description='Descripton'+CONVERT(nvarchar(15),@Counter) where ID>=1
     set @Counter=@Counter+1
      end
```

Comment: Running queries in a set based fashion is _much_ faster than row by row (e.g. while loops, cursors etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `cursor` needed, just a simple `update`:

```
update Person
set Description = "Description" + convert(varchar(10), ID)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer       [aF](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187730/af)

Comment: `convert(varchar` without length? I don't recommend it. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand indeed, 10 should be more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  Person
SET     Discription = SPACE(Z.n)+ Z.Discription
FROM (  SELECT  ID, 
                Description , 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)n
        FROM Person
    )Z
```

Comment: thank for your answer  [mehdi lotfi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1407421/mehdi-lotfi)(mamnon agha mehdi)